# AWS SES: Send templated email with template create by another account

Tags: aws-sdk, amazon-iam, amazon-ses

I have a build setup whereby we create SES templates with one user, but we want to send them with another user. I can send templated emails when the template was created by the same user as the one sending, but when I try to send via a different account I get accessdenied. Is this expected? Is there a permission I need to grant to be able to allow this?

I found in the Php docs (though I'm using the CLI and jave/javascript sdks) that templates should be accessible to any account authed for that region but it's not working for us (
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/ses-template.html)

Any help appreciated!

Comment: My guess is that you need to use sending authorization policy(to allow cross account) to a verified identitiy which allows the send template (get/list etc) actions.

Comment: Thanks for the thought but I don't think you can do that with sendtemplatedemail https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/sending-authorization-policies.html